# Line Art modifier doesn't work

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, lineart

I think I’ll do everything right, but still I don’t see line art, only emptiness.
[My Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lRddQV29BrTexj5O9UtM-vKAmDra1dwW/view?usp=sharing)

My system info:
System - Windows 10
CPU - Intel core i5
GPU - Geforce 820M

Comment: Perspective　×　/　Orthographic　○

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have done everything right, however, in order for it to work, you must have a camera in the scene, and the camera view must be selected.

[image: ![enter image description here]